# Selecting from a table contains a XML column

Tags: sql-server, import, xml

I have received an Excel file (verion 2010) and based on the requirement I was asked to save it as an XML file and then import into SQL data ready to be queried in normal SELECT statements.

Below is the list of steps I followed but now that I have a SELECT on the data, no records is returned. I'm not sure whether it's due to the conversion that I did to get an XML file from an Excel file, or there is a problem in my `OPENXML` query.

1. To obtain a `XML` file from the `.xlsx` file, I opend the file in
   EXCEL 2010 and saved it in 'XML spread sheet 2003 (*.XML)'.
2. I imported the XML file in a table using the code below:

   ```
   INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
   SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\DEV\TestXML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;


   SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML
   ```

[image]
 1. The XML data has been stored now in the table, so I use the code below to read it in a SELECT statement to access the individual columns:

```
    DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)


 SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML


    SELECT SNo,Salutation,PatientNRIC,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Race
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/SNo/Salutation/PatientNRIC/FirstName/LastName/Gender/Race')
    WITH 
    (
        SNo [nvarchar](50) '@SNo',
        Salutation [nvarchar](100) '@Salutation',
        PatientNRIC [nvarchar](255) '@PatientNRIC',
        FirstName [nvarchar](255) '@FirstName',
        LastName [nvarchar](255) '@LastName',
        Gender [nvarchar](255) '@Gender',
        Race [nvarchar](255) '@Race'
    )
```

Then

```
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
    GO
```

However what I get is only the name of columns, the actual data has not been returned:

[image]

I am totally new to OPENXML comment and working with XML files, tried reading different posts but still couldn't figure out why no data is shown in my select query. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to import it as XML instead of converting it to xml, and then populating a table from the XML? The only reason I ask is that the way you are trying to do it may not work as expected due to the shared string table, embedded functions, sheet/cell references etc.. FYI, Excel 2010 is a collection of XML files - change the extension from xlsx to zip and the extract the contents to see for yourself.

Comment: You need to study how to query XML in SQL Server using the XML datatype. Have a look at [Stariway to XML](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/92778/) at SQL Server Central.  Level 1,2 and 4 should be enough for you to solve this on your own.

Comment: Also, an `XLS` sheet has a limit of 65K rows, which was increased significantly in 2010 when they moved to the `XLSX` format. Converting to the lesser `XLS` format can result in data loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your XML is held in a table you can use the [methods of the XML data-type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798(v=sql.110).aspx) ( eg .nodes, .value, .query etc ).  The thing you might struggle with a bit is namespaces in XML.  Start here to learn more about them: [Understanding XML Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx).

Here are a few example queries I did against a spreadsheet similar to yours.  Try them and work through the Stairway as suggested by @MikaelEriksson and see if they start to make sense.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp
GO


-- 1) Pull the data "as is" unpivoted, tag it with row/cell numbers
-- and optionally pivot it
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 
    DEFAULT 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet',
    'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' AS ss   
    ), cte AS (
SELECT
    t.rawXMLId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) rowNumber,
    r.c.query('.') rowXML
FROM XMLwithOpenXML t
    CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('Workbook/Worksheet[@ss:Name = "Sheet1"]') w(c)
        CROSS APPLY w.c.nodes('Table/Row') r(c)
)
SELECT
    c.rawXMLId,
    c.rowNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY rowNUmber ORDER BY rowNumber ) cellNumber,
    d.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS cellData
INTO #tmp
FROM cte c
    CROSS APPLY c.rowXML.nodes('Row/Cell/Data') d(c)
GO


SELECT 'unpivoted' s, *
FROM #tmp

SELECT 
    'pivoted' s,
    rawXMLId, rowNumber, 
    [1] AS Sno,
    [2] AS Salutation,
    [3] AS PatientNRIC,
    [4] AS FirstName,
    [5] AS LastName,
    [6] AS Gender,
    [7] AS Race
FROM #tmp
PIVOT ( MAX(cellData) For cellNumber In ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] )  ) upvt
GO



-- 2) Use your knowledge about the data to specify the columns manually
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 
    DEFAULT 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet',
    'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' AS ss   
    )
SELECT 
    t.rawXMLId,
    d.c.value('(Cell/Data/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Sno,
    d.c.value('(Cell/Data/text())[2]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Salutation,
    d.c.value('(Cell/Data/text())[3]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS PatientNRIC,
    d.c.value('(Cell/Data/text())[4]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS FirstName,
    d.c.value('(Cell/Data/text())[5]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS LastName,
    d.c.value('(Cell/Data/text())[6]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Gender,
    d.c.value('(Cell/Data/text())[7]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Race

FROM XMLwithOpenXML t
    CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('Workbook/Worksheet[@ss:Name = "Sheet1"]') w(c)
        --CROSS APPLY w.c.nodes('Table/Row') d(c)                   <-- include row header
        CROSS APPLY w.c.nodes('Table/Row[position() > 1]') d(c)     -- exclude row header

GO
```

My results:

[image: Test results]

Just a note about `OPENXML`, it can be good for larger pieces of XML but I tend to try and avoid it if possible due it's well known memory issues.  Your particular example is not working because of the namespaces and you have specified the wrong path (Root etc).  Post back if you really want to work with the `OPENXML`, but I would advise against it in this example as your data is held in a table - `OPENXML` can only work with once piece of XML at a time.